# Is it possible to join 2 Kafka KStreams where the JoinWindows duration is stored in the object of 1 of the streams?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Let say I have 2 streams:

1. TimeWindow (with begin time, end time)
2. Numbers (with time stamp)

Is it possible to user either DSL API or Process API to join the streams such that the output will contain TimeWindow object that contains the sum of the numbers that is within the time range specified in TimeWindow?
To be specific, how do you set XXX where it is the duration store in **win.getDuration()** where **win** is the one referenced in ValueJoiner.

```
timeWindow.join(  
    numbers,   
    (ValueJoiner<TimeWindow, Number, TimeWindow>) (win, num) -> win.addToTotal(num),  
    new JoinWindows(XXX, 0)
).to("output_Topic");
```

The JoinWindows after is 0 because TimeWindow's timestamp is endtime. XXX duration should be calculate as TimeWindows end time - begin time in milli seconds.

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: It's not possible using the DSL, but with Processor API you can build anything :) But giving advice how is beyond the scope what SO can provide. It's a pretty deep question. You will need to use a custom store and write your own `Processor` that compute the join...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Matthias' incite, I end up roll back to use Processor API with the implementation of TimestampExtractors and usage of in memory state store (default to use RockDB) to implemented this function.